Lua Minimalization (literally minimizing it to it's smallest format)
The issue, not really an issue, is something I am interested to learn. It is how to minimize my code so it literally becomes the smallest format it can possibly.
My best work (In Lua by the way) on this is as shows:
local p = {"celeb","celery","carnita","bobby","logno","1x1x1","invalidcharacter"} local u = coroutine.create( function() for i,v in ipairs(p) do print("uscan", i) coroutine.yield() end end) for i=1,#p do coroutine.resume(u) end

I need to find out if I can shorten function coroutine to be assigned to string "c" and if I can take player list "p" to shorten it somehow, and since this is going to be implemented into Roblox Studio, aka Roblox as a whole, it also needs support for LuaU, documentation here. What I do not want to do however is encoding/hexidecimal, like the 0xA09B or whatever, it's because, like binairy, is ineffecient, and hard to decode. I only need a function to simplify other functions, like coroutine to "c" and similar keywords shortened.
I have tried things like
local e = end

but as you expect, this didn't work since the keyword ends the running code. so, I can't thing of anything else to solve this issue however.

why would you want to do that? that's pretty bad style

You can shorten identifiers like coroutine. Just local c=coroutine will work (or even just c=coroutine if you don't care about polluting the global namespace). You could go further, e.g., with local r=c.resume. You cannot shorten keywords like end.

Thank you, also, I haven't done lua in a while, yk, but I'm getting back into it. Are there other identifiers you can shorten?

@X078 You can shorten every identifier.
